# How to round number to two digits in JavsScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, fixed-point

I have the following number `704.425` that need to round to `704.43`. Is I use `.toFixed(2)` I get `704.42` instead.

```
console.log(704.425.toFixed(2)) // 704.42
```

How could I get `704.43` instead `704.42` ?

Comment: `Math.round(704.425*100)/100`

Comment: Several results in Google, this is about the 4th: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rounding.htm